# Why cant I import a simple class?

Tags: python, import

Im writing an addon and with all my code in an ****init**.py** file. It works without any problem. My issue is that I want to separate a lengthy class I've made into its own separate .py file to better organize and expand my project as to not create a bloated single file.

When I try to use `from foo_file import Foo_Class`, python doesn't recognize the file name even though all my files are in the same directory. All my other files that has an Operator, Panel or PropertyGroup class are seen.

My **foo_file.py** is in no special format. Its job is just to do a series of operations within my Operator classes:

```
class Foo_Class:
     def __init__(self, bar1, bar2, bar3):
         self.bar1 = bar1
         self.bar2 = bar2
         self.bar3 = bar3
    
     def a_func(self):
         pass

     def b_func(self):
         pass
```

The error message I receive is

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo_file'
```

Comment: `from . foo_file import Foo_Class`?

Comment: @XY even with the period, the file name isnt recognized

Comment: can you paste the error traceback?

Comment: @MartyFouts I updated with the error